# Incomplete orders - they add to order ID?

Tags: expresso-store

I see that Store adds the order ID to incomplete orders.

So there is no accumulative counting of proper orders (orders miss IDS). Is there a way to change this so only actual orders receive an order ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Store creates an ID for each cart, not only incomplete orders. Currently there is no way around this. In the future we would like to take the current ID and call it a Cart ID and add a separate Order ID for complete orders.